# How to modify a bestsellers block to display products from specific category?

Tags: php, magento

I'm fairly new to Magento 1.9.0.1 and have installed a third party theme. It has 4 sets of sliders on the home page which each show different lists of products such as best sellers, most viewed and so on.

I'm attempting to replace one of these (best sellers) with simply a list of products from a specific category. According to the theme author this can be done the following block file:

```
<?php
class Magentothem_Bestsellerproductslider_Block_Bestsellerproductslider extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

protected function useFlatCatalogProduct()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product');
}

public function getBestsellerproductslider()     
{ 
    if (!$this->hasData('bestsellerproductslider')) {
        $this->setData('bestsellerproductslider', Mage::registry('bestsellerproductslider'));
    }
    return $this->getData('bestsellerproductslider');
}
public function getProducts()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('bestsellerproductslider/product_bestseller')
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ;
    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');

    // getNumProduct
    $collection->setPageSize($this->getConfig('qty'));

    if($this->useFlatCatalogProduct())
    {
        // fix error mat image vs name while Enable useFlatCatalogProduct
        foreach ($collection as $product) 
        {
            $productId = $product->_data['entity_id'];
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); //Product ID
            $product->_data['name']        = $_product->getName();
            $product->_data['thumbnail']   = $_product->getThumbnail();
            $product->_data['small_image'] = $_product->getSmallImage();
        }            
    }       

    $this->setProductCollection($collection);
}
public function getConfig($att) 
{
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('bestsellerproductslider');
    if (isset($config['bestsellerproductslider_config']) ) {
        $value = $config['bestsellerproductslider_config'][$att];
        return $value;
    } else {
        throw new Exception($att.' value not set');
    }
}

function cut_string_bestsellerproductslider($string,$number){ 
        if(strlen($string) <= $number) {
            return $string;
        }
        else {  
            if(strpos($string," ",$number) > $number){
                $new_space = strpos($string," ",$number);
                $new_string = substr($string,0,$new_space)."..";
                return $new_string;
            }
            $new_string = substr($string,0,$number)."..";
            return $new_string;
        }
}
}
```

I just can't see how I can change this to work for my needs. I know some PHP but this code is pretty alien to me!

Comment: Here getProducts() is the function which is setting the product collection for you. You need to modify this function to get data from a particular category.

Comment: Check the below link how to get products from a category. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/get-product-collection-from-a-category-id